# How to do the mappings for joins with OR conditions using Hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, persistence

I am trying to do the mappings and trying to write a non-native HQL query by joining the 4 tables. The logic is written in stored procedure, but we want to migrate it to hibernate/JPA. I am unable to do proper mappings and write a query to create same logic

```
FROM
[dbo].[vwInstitutionUser]AS IU
INNER JOIN [dbo].[vwCommonCourse] AS C
ON C.CustomerID=CAST(IU.InstitutionID AS VARCHAR(10))
INNER JOIN [dbo].[vwCommonCourses] AS CM
ON C.CourseID = CM.CourseID
INNER JOIN dbo.vwProductMaster AS PM
ON CM.LearningActivityID = PM.ResourceID
OR CM.AssessmentID = PM.AssessmentID
WHERE
IU.UserID = @UserID 
AND PM.IsCert = CASE WHEN @SubReportID='MACS' THEN PM.IsCert ELSE 
@IsCert END
ORDER BY PM.IsCert, PM.ResourceName
```

Please let me know if anybody has same use case, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure if I undrestand you correctly, but i would recommend you the following actions:

- Each inner join can be mapped as a relation within JPA (`@OneToMany`,
  `@OneToOne`, `@ManyToOne`,`@ManyToMany`)
- Ordering can be implemented with [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface on entity level
- For the computed values i would suggest to use sql computed value or service layer within your business logic which will provide you those values (`@Transient` field)
- You can also write [NativeQuery](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/query_native.html) for you model

Hope that i answered at least some of your questions :)